# How to set a proxy on a QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: qt, proxy, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I want to get the webpage source code of http://www.youtube.com/  ,but youtube is blocked in my country ,so I decided to access it by a proxy server – hostname : 127.0.0.1  port :8087

according to the documentation I think use

```
void QNetworkAccessManager::setProxyFactory ( QNetworkProxyFactory * factory )
```

is a good choice for me ,but I don’t know how to associate this function with my proxy server at all ,I googled a lot ,but found it very hard to find an example on how to using this function ,anyone can show me how to use it on my needs here ?

only showing me how to use this function is enough ,I know how to get the webpage source code

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a subclass of `QNetworkProxyFactory` and reimplement `queryProxy` virtual method.

```
QList<QNetworkProxy> MyNetworkProxyFactory::queryProxy (const QNetworkProxyQuery & query) {
  QNetworkProxy proxy;
  if (query.url().host() == "www.youtube.com") {
    // modify 'proxy' variable according to your proxy
  }
  return QList<QNetworkProxy>() << proxy;
}
```

Comment: 1)QNetworkProxyFactory::queryProxy is automatically called when a new QnetworkProxyFactory is created ,right ?
2)I think return one  QNetworkProxy object is enough ,but QNetworkProxyFactory::queryProxy returns a list of QNetworkProxy ,what is the purpose of returning a list of QNetworkProxy ?

Comment: 1) No, `queryProxy` will be called once per request. You need to register your factory after creating using `QNetworkAccessManager::setProxyFactory`. 2) `QNetworkProxyFactory::queryProxy ` returns a list of appropriate proxy servers in order of preference. If you want to use a single proxy server, you need to return a list containing one element. It's a virtual function used by Qt internally, so you can't change its return type.

Comment: Since I use this QNetworkProxyQuery, when I receive a QNetworkReply, how do I know which proxy this reply from?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass `QNetworkProxyFactory` and override `QNetworkProxyFactory::queryProxy` then. Return a `QNetworkProxy` for your localhost proxy for request URLs directed to Youtube, and a default proxy otherwise.

Comment: thanks ,but I don't want to use the same proxy value for all requests.
setProxyFactory is my favorite

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Changed my answer.

Comment: 1)QNetworkProxyFactory::queryProxy is automatically called when a new QnetworkProxyFactory is created ,right ?
2)I think return one  QNetworkProxy object is enough ,but QNetworkProxyFactory::queryProxy returns a list of QNetworkProxy ,what is the purpose of returning a list of QNetworkProxy ?